# regular expression replace with prototype?

Tags: javascript, regex, prototype

I got some html formatted in the following way:

```
[Title|<a class="external" href="http://test.com">http://test.com</a>]
```

From these texts I'd like to create links using "Title" as the text and "http://test.com" as link. How can I best do this in prototype?

Comment: How do you want your final output to be ?

Comment: Hi DhruvPathak, the output should be: <a class="external" href="http://test.com">Title</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex that will retain the original attributes of the anchor tag while doing the replacement:

```
var link = "[Title|<a class=\"external\" href=\"http://test.com\">http://test.com</a>]";
var pattern = /\[([^|]+)\|([^>]+.?)[^<]*(<\/a>)\]/;
link.replace(pattern, "$2$1$3"));
```

The output is:

```
<a class="external" href="http://test.com">Title</a>
```

Comment: Hi Adam, How can I make it iterate through an entire div? I've been trying to get this to work but I'm still failing: http://jsfiddle.net/JFC72/2/

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle to replace each one using `/g` at the end of the regex pattern. http://jsfiddle.net/JFC72/9/

Comment: Hey Adam, unfortunately it only appends to #formatted instead of replacing them as requested, how can I fix this? Many thanks!

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle so that it replaced the original text per your requirement: http://jsfiddle.net/JFC72/15/

Comment: Awesome, that completely works! Last stupid question; I have to implement this on a class instead of on an id, which appears to be more difficult, any idea on how to accomplish this? As always, many thanks man :)

Comment: Well, it depends on if you have access to a library like jQuery (or the many others) that come with a CSS selector engine (like Sizzle) that makes it easy to select DOM elements based on things like the `class` name.  Here is an example using jQuery and a `class`: http://jsfiddle.net/magicaj/JFC72/18/ - If you are not already using a 3rd party library I would be hesitant to add one just for this one function unless you plan to use more of it since it does add a significant amount of JavaScript to the page.  You might consider a smaller library: http://code.google.com/p/getelementsbyclassname/

Answer (score 2):

Pure RegExp:

```
var ProperLink=WierdString.replace(/\[([^|]+)\|(<[^>]+>)[^<]+[^\]]+\]/,'$2$1</a>')
```

in the context you provided:

```
function convert(id){
    $(id).innerHTML=$(id).innerHTML.replace(/\[([^|]+)\|(<[^>]+>)[^<]+[^\]]+\]/g,'$2$1</a>');
}
convert('testdiv');
```

Comment: Nice Shad! Do you know how I can implement it in an example such as: http://jsfiddle.net/JFC72/1/  ? Thanks man :)

Comment: Thanks Chad, but I can't get it to work though : / Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/JFC72/13/  -- Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Without prototype: http://jsfiddle.net/JFC72/  , you can use prototype to make it simpler.

```
var myStr = "[THIS IS TITLE|http://test.com]";
document.getElementById('testdiv').innerHTML =  getLink(myStr);


function getLink(myStr)
{
var splitted = myStr.split("|http");
var title = splitted[0].substring(1);
var href = splitted[1].substring(0,splitted[1].length-1);
return "<a href='http" + href + "'>" + title + "</a>";

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm having difficulties implementing this though, please see: http://jsfiddle.net/JFC72/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var dummyDiv = document.createElement('div');
dummyDiv.innerHTML = '[Title|<a class="external ...';

var parts = dummyDiv.innerText.slice(1, -1).split('|');
// parts[0] is the text, parts[1] is the URL
```

Comment: hmmm.. I think parts[1] is `<a class="external" href="blah">BLAH</a>` and FLX wanted a linked version of your `parts[0]`

Comment: @Shad - `parts[1]` should just be the url, without any HTML. I imagine @FLX can create an anchor node using the text, and the URL. see http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/9LhA3/